# Entity Framework can't import Stored procedure performing FTS

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, full-text-search, entity-framework-5

I'm running MSSQL 2012 with the FTS engine enabled. I have the following sproc which performs full-text searching on a varchar column:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [PROE].[SP_SearchLabOrdersByPatientNameAndDateRange]
    @searchString varchar(160)
    , @dtFrom datetime
    , @dtTo datetime
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT ord.Id, ord.FullName, ord.SomeOtherColumns
    FROM
        PROE.PatientLabOrders ord
    WHERE
        FREETEXT(ord.FullName, @searchString)
        AND ord.OrderDateTime BETWEEN @dtFrom AND @dtTo
```

When I import the above stored procedure, the EDM model designer doesn't show any DTO column information. Instead, the model browser displays the following message:

> The Selected Stored Procedure or Function returns no columns

Image is:

[image]

I have a few variations of this sproc which perform regular (not FTS) searching on other columns - all of those sprocs are imported properly by EF 5. Only the above sproc is using full-text searching. I've run the above stored procedure in SQL server manager and it's returning rows as expected. Yet the EF5 designer still can't detect columns returned by the sproc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know nothing of your problem, but having looked at this by chance, can the reason be that you selected "none" as the returned type?

Comment: @ynka: Thanks for the prompt reply. The "None" option was selected by default by EDM designer. I tried forcing return type (complex entity type previously imported from similar sprocs) onto it - to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

its because you need to use the return keyword and return the column you are looking for i have no experience of doing this so im not going to post a query of google and hope it work but i do no this is your problem just google return column.